# open source C# proxy server - any projects/examples?

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener, proxy-server

Anyone know of any open source C# proxy server projects?  Otherwise any articles/tutorials that cover how to use C# classes to get proxy server basic functionality working (in particularly for HTTPS requests)

The only one I have found so far (and I will look at) is: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Mini Proxy Server in Sharp](http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/).
It supports both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: "Mini Proxy Server in Sharp" is a waste of time. No source code available. :(

Comment: @roy davis: http://www.ilspy.net/‎ C# decompiler. But still a waste of time, because it uses COM interop, so it is non-portable.

Comment: here is the source code of the prject http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/releases/view/35966

Comment: @doekman it sounds like you have to focus on the page open your eyes and you will see MiniProxyServer_SourceCode with green icon it is about (0cm(x),9cm(y)) location of the page or here is the link for direct download after you click on MiniProxyServer_SourceCode http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/downloads/get/93072

Comment: @doekman if you want a proxy with no icon-tray i have cracked the version of http://www.privoxy.org/ now no icon-tray it runs hiden on the background and it is the best web proxy tool

Answer (score 3):

Checkout below project. Its a HTTPS supporting proxy server

https://github.com/titanium007/Titanium

Answer (score 1):

Mini Proxy Server in Sharp

source code of the link for that is here :

[Source Code here](http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/releases/view/35966)

or direct link download

[Direct link download](http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/downloads/get/93072)